# Topological embedding iff $X$ homeomorphic to $f(X)$

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that $f: X \to Y$ is an embedding iff it induces a homeo $\tilde f: X \to f(X)$.

Recall that an injective homeo is an embedding if $\tau_X = \{f^{-1}(V): V \in \tau_Y \}$.

Now, if $f$ is an embedding, because for all $V$ open in $Y$ we have $f^{-1}(V) = \tilde f^{-1}(V \cap f(X))$, $\tilde f$ is a homeo.

Conversely, suppose we have a homeo $\tilde f : X \to f(X)$. We want to prove that $\tau_X = \{f^{-1}(V): V \in \tau_Y \}$. Clearly, since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(V) \in \tau_X$ for all $Y \in \tau_Y$. How can I prove these are the only opens? I guess I should also use $f$ injective somewhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any open set $U\subset X$.
Since $\tilde f$ is a homeomorphism, the image $\tilde f(U)\subset Y$ is open in $f(X)$.
A homeomorphism always maps an open set to an open set, as can be seen by using the definition of continuity for the inverse $\tilde f^{-1}$.
By the definition of the relative topology of $f(X)\subset Y$, there is an open set $V\subset Y$ so that $\tilde f(U)=f(X)\cap V$.

Now: $$f^{-1}(V)=\tilde f^{-1}(V)=\tilde f^{-1}(\tilde f(U))=U$$ so $U$ is of the desired form.

Comment: Everything clear, but I really can't grasp why, if $U$ is open in $X$, then $\tilde f (U) \subseteq f(X)$ is open in $f(X)$.

Comment: @FrancescoGemma It's because a homeomorphism always maps an open set to an open set. The easiest way to see this is using continuity of the inverse: the image under a function is the same as the preimage under the inverse because the function is bijective. I can elaborate on this later if you want.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but I'm a bit rusty with topology. I've just remembered that "homeomorphism" in Top means "continuos with inverse continuous"! I always use morphism in the categorical sense and so I kept thinking "homeo" meant just "continuous"... Thanks a lot! Everything's obvious, now.

Comment: @FrancescoGemma You're welcome! The morphisms in Top are called "continuous functions", so I see why it can be confusing from a categorical point of view, especially with "homeomorphism" looking so much like "homomorphism".

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $\tilde f:X\to f(X)$ is a homeomorphism tells us that there is a one-to-one correspondence between sets open in $X$ and sets open in $f(X)$.

More precisely the maps $\phi:\tau_X\to\tau_{f(X)}$ and $\theta:\tau_{f(X)}\to\tau_X$ prescribed by $U\mapsto f(U)$ and $V\mapsto f^{-1}(V)$ respectively are inverses of each other.

So for $U\in\tau_X$ we find: $$U=\theta\phi(U)=f^{-1}(f(U))$$where $f(U)\in\tau_{f(X)}$.

This means that $f(U)=f(X)\cap V$ for some $V\in\tau_Y$ so that $U=f^{-1}(f(X)\cap V)=f^{-1}(V)$.

Comment: Same doubt as in the other answer. Why is $\phi$ well defined? That is, why is $f(U)$ open in $f(X)$ if $U$ is open in $\tau_X$?

Comment: Because by definition (or maybe almost by definition. That depends on what definition is practicized) a homeomorphism sends open sets to open sets.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but I'm a bit rusty with topology. I've just remembered that "homeomorphism" in Top means "continuos with inverse continuous"! I always use morphism in the categorical sense and so I kept thinking "homeo" meant just "continuous"... Thanks a lot! Everything's obvious, now.

Comment: You are welcome. A homeomorphism can be described as an *isomorphism* in the category $\mathbf{Top}$. It has a look-a-like with *homomorphism* which on its turn is only a morphism. That might have caused your confusion.